# Ruby on Rails check that multiple values aren't blank or equal to each other

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, conditional-statements

I have a form in a ruby on rails site that takes in a bunch of different parameters.  I want to ensure that none of these parameters equal each other IF they are not blank.  With how the form is designed, none of these values are required, so some of them can be blank.  I can do this with a conditional statement of course, but I wanted to ensure whether or not there is a cleaner way to do so as the conditional statement would be HUGE with all of those checks.  Again, if any of the values are equal to each other when (and only when) those values are chosen, I want to return an error that they can not be equal.  The values are chosen by collection_select controls, so I'm not seeing any way to filter out duplicates beforehand. Is there a more concise way to compare all of these values?

```
if ((value1 == value2) && !value2.blank?) || 
   ((value1 == value3) && !value3.blank?) ||
   ((value1 == value4) && !value4.blank?) ||
   .... 
   ((value9 == value10) && !value10.blank?))
    Do error stuff
else
    Behave normally
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the cleanest way of which I can think, assuming you don't need to know *which* elements are equal:

1. I assume the items are in an array (or a collection that can easily be turned into an array). Regardless, somehow land them in this form.

   ```
   ary = [value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6,value7,value8,value9,value10]
   ```
2. Drop the blank items.

   ```
   ary.reject!(|value| value.blank?)
   ```
3. Find out if there are more elements than *unique* elements

   ```
   if ary.length > ary.uniq.length
       # Do error stuff
   else
       # Behave Normally
   end
   ```

**Note:**

This approach may be clean to read and highly scalable (an array of 100 elements with this approach is far more efficient than 100 elsifs). However, if your data is not in an easily-array-ready form (i.e. already in an array, hash, or other enumerable) the assignment into an array may not be worth the cost.

Furthermore, as aforementioned, this only returns *if* values are shared, not *which values* are shared, or *which variables* share values.

Additionally, for step 2, if the only values for which you're checking `.blank?` are `nil`, you could simply use `ary.compact!` instead.

Answer (score 0):

First, errors and form / data validations should really be model-layer stuff. So you should consider moving this to a validation on the model, and then ActiveRecord errors + something like simple_form will make error raising / rendering a breeze.

Back to your question - are you using Rails 4? If so, like Connor mentions, simply add a little logic to strip out blank params values in your `permit!`

```
class ExampleController < ApplicationController

  private
  def permitted_params
    params.require(:example).permit(:a, :b, :c).reject!(&:blank?)
  end
end
```

Then, your logic becomes simpler and you can just compare values... which at this point I would add to your model layer

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  validate: :must_be_different

  private
  def must_be_different
    # compare value1 with value2 (take advantage of _changed? helper)
  end
end
```